# Application pool not working after registering aspnet_regiis

Tags: windows-7, iis-8, aspnet-regiis.exe

I've installed the iis 7 and afterwards I've checked that the localhost is work ing under .net 2.After that checked worked fine, I've registered the aspnet_regiis in order to work with .net 4.5 applications on his but after the registration (and allowing .net 4 in the isapi in iis) the localhost returns and 503 error unavailableAfter checking the event viewer, the only error shown from the iis is the following:

`"The worker process for application pool 'DefaultAppPool, encountered an error 'Configuration file is not well-formed XML' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\web.config', line number '58'. The data field contains the error code."`

Jut to let you know, I haven't changed or modified the web.config file at all and that all occupied just after registering the aspnet_regiis.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can just post line 58 from the file?

Comment: I've found the solution. The McAfee did it and after removing it, the error has gone and everything worked fine